# Using jQuery to iterate across like named checkboxes

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to use jQuery each() to iterate across a group of checkboxes named supplier_type[].  They all have unique ids so I could just re-write this to handle an array of unique ids but I wanted to figure out where I went wrong here.

The alert shows that while intIndex sees the correct number of elements `this` always holds the first element.

```
function setUp(){
    $( 'input[name=supplier_type[]]' ).each(
        function( intIndex ){
            var type = $(this+':checked').val() + 'Table';
            $("#"+type).show("slow");
            alert($(this+':checked').val());  // sees first one each iter
        }       
    );
}
```

So how do I address the correct element?  Do I need to use bind()?

Thanks!

// Edit
Working version based on Drew Wills response.  Thanks Drew!

```
function setUp(){
    $( 'input[name=supplier_type[]]' ).each(
        function( intIndex ){
            if($(this).attr('checked')) {
                var type = $(this).val() + 'Table';
                $("#"+type).show("slow");
            }
        }       
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but I'm very suspicious of the following style of selector:

```
$(this+':checked')
```

I'm guessing you want to know the value of the 'checked' attribute, which would be more like...

```
$(this).attr('checked')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Am I misusing this?  http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: The ':checked' selector matches instances that are checked, it doesn't tell you whether a given instance is checked or not.  What do you get if you do alert(this+':checked')?  I'm surprised that this concatenated string matches anything at all.